# react native failed to install firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native

I am trying to install firebase to my react native project. To do so I have tried several ways based on few sources. I open cmd, move to the project's directory, and tried these:

1. `npm install --save firebase`
2. `npm install firebase --save`
3. `npm i react-native-firebase --save`

But unfortunately, none of this is able to install the firebase to my react native project. For the no 1 and 2, it says:

```
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
```

For no 3 it says:

```
npm ERR! path C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\auth\node_modules\react-native-firebase
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\auth\node_modules\react-native-firebase' -> 'C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\auth\node_modules\.react-native-firebase.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

And of course when I tried to import the firebase and run my apps, is shows error code 500 with failed to resolve firebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing cached .npm directory stored from the previous versions of npm. It is placed at ~/.npm 

i.e.

```
rm -rf ~/.npm
```

Look at [this](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16677) issue for further help.